# How to get path to project in pipleline Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to ask how to get path to project (repository) in pipeline (yaml syntax) Azure Devops?

Comment: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. For a other predefined variable, see this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables

Comment: How's your issue going? Is Krzysztof Madej's reply helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s` or `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` for single repo, but if you use muli repo please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path)

> If you have multiple checkout steps in your job, your source code is checked out into directories named after the repositories as a subfolder of s in (Agent.BuildDirectory). If `(Agent.BuildDirectory)` is `C:\agent\_work\1` and your repositories are named `tools` and `code`, your code is checked out to `C:\agent\_work\1\s\tools` and `C:\agent\_work\1\s\code`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` [System-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) or `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` [Build-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) returns the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. (repo root dir) 
For example: `c:\agent_work\1\s`